# can we find the data and modify the oprater name from result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

data:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5874a303414af4d70e3c988d"),
    "trade" : "XYZ",
    "sub_trade" : [ 
        "ABC1", 
        "ABC2", 
        "ABC3", 
        "ABC14", 
        "ABC15"
    ]
  }
```

shall we change index of sub_trade to trade value dynamically

accepting output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5874a303414af4d70e3c988d"),
    "trade" : "XYZ",
    "XYZ" : [ 
        "ABC1", 
        "ABC2", 
        "ABC3", 
        "ABC14", 
        "ABC15"
    ]
  }
```

please help me out

Comment: You can't do such operations in MongoDB, you'd need to use the bracket notation in JavaScript to manipulate the result though, like `data[data["trade"]] = data["sub_trade"]; delete data["sub_trade"];`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want something like this:

```
data['sub_trade'] = data['trade'];
delete data['trade'];
```

edit: If you want to change when querying use Mongos projection

```
{
    "$project": {
        "sub_trade": "trade"
    }
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: i don't want to modify after query shall we can modify in query it self while finding data from data base